# TypeORM Datasource intialization error, Cannot read properties of undefined at Entity

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, relational-database, typeorm

I'm building a microservice node app with typeorm as the entity mapper with mysql database. I'm having an intialization error of datasource configuration of typeorm. can anyone help me with this issue as I'm very new to typeorm. Thanks.

**Datasource intialization**

```
module.exports = async (app: Application) => {

    // initialize mysql datasource
    MySQLDataSource.initialize()
    .then(() => console.log("MySQL Datasource has been successfully initialized"))
    .catch(e => console.error("Error initializing mysql datasource", e));
    
    // configuring necessary properties for server
    app.use(express.json());

    // controller configuration
    TuitionController(app);
}
```

**Datasource configuration**

```
export const MySQLDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "ignite_tuition_node_db",
    entities: ["dist/entities/*.js"],
});
```

**Only entity**

```
/**
 * Tuition entity
 */
@Entity()
class Tuition {

    private TUITION_ID_PREFIX: string = "tid-";

    @PrimaryColumn()
    private id: string;
    @Column({ nullable: false })
    private name: string;
    @Column({ nullable: false })
    private location: string;
    private studentIds: Set<string> = new Set();

    private constructor(requestDto: TuitionCreateRequestDto) {
        this.id = this.TUITION_ID_PREFIX + randomUUID();
        this.name = requestDto.getProperty(DtoProperty.NAME);
        this.location = requestDto.getProperty(DtoProperty.LOCATION);
    }

    public getProperty(property: EntityProperty): any {
        if (property === EntityProperty.ID)
            return this.id;
        if (property === EntityProperty.NAME)
            return this.name;
        if (property === EntityProperty.LOCATION)
            return this.location;
        return this.studentIds;
    }

    private addStudentId(studentId: string): void {
        this.studentIds.add(studentId);
    }

    private removeStudentId(studentId: string): void {
        this.studentIds.delete(studentId);
    }
}

export default Tuition;
```

**Stack trace**

```
Debugger attached.
Express application server running on address=> http://localhost:8000
Error initializing mysql datasource TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProperty')
    at new Tuition (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-tuition-nodejs\dist\entities\Tuition.js:25:32)
    at EntityMetadata.create (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-tuition-nodejs\node_modules\src\metadata\EntityMetadata.ts:563:23)
    at EntityMetadataValidator.validate (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-tuition-nodejs\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataValidator.ts:211:47)
    at D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-tuition-nodejs\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataValidator.ts:43:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataValidator.validateMany (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-tuition-nodejs\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataValidator.ts:42:25)
    at DataSource.buildMetadatas (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-tuition-nodejs\node_modules\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:724:33)
    at async DataSource.initialize (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-tuition-nodejs\node_modules\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:259:13)
```

Comment: The error message is clear, the `requestDto` is `undefined`,

Comment: how did you get that requestdto is undefined. and any idea how to debug why?? and if I add this property ```entitySkipConstructor: true,``` to ```MySQLDataSource``` this issue is passing, but don't know what it is doing.